# Bash script hangs when filtering stderr through sed

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel, process-substitution

##### Introduction

I have a `bash` script to execute a command in multiple servers through `ssh`. It uses GNU `parallel` in the parallel version, a for loop in the sequential one.

The script is used like this:

```bsh
foreach_server "cd $dir && find -name '*.png' | wc -l"
foreach_server "cd $dir && git --no-pager status"
```

Sometimes I need to have access to executables in `conda` environments (https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/) and the only way I found to make this work is to use an interactive shell, that is, use `bash -ic` before the commands I want to execute, like so, `ssh $host bash -ic $cmd`, so that the conda environment is loaded. This unfortunately causes two error messages on `stderr`, which I was not able to prevent:

```
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
```

So I made a filter with `sed` which removes these two lines from `stderr` and passes on the other lines in `stderr`:

```bsh
ssh $host "$@" 2> >(sed -e "$filter1" -e "$filter2" >&2)
```

##### Problem: the sed filter makes the parallel version hang

The `sed` filter  works fine in the sequential version, but the parallel version hangs at the end of the script, showing that the sed process is alive but doing no work. How can I prevent this?

I suspect that the problem lies in the process substitution, but I really cannot diagnose what is wrong.

##### Referenced script

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
set -u

exit_trap() {
    echo "Interrupted"
    exit 1
}

trap exit_trap SIGINT

filter1='/^bash: cannot set terminal process group/d'
filter2='/^bash: no job control in this shell/d' 

hosts=("host1" "host2")  # more hosts in the real file

if [ -z ${serial+x} ];
then
    # Parallel version ==> THIS VERSION HANGS AT THE END, AFTER ALL OUTPUT HAS BEEN WRITTEN
    echo ${hosts[@]} | sed 's/ /\n/g' | parallel "echo ----- {} ----- && ssh {} \"$@\"" 2> >(sed -e "$filter1" -e "$filter2" >&2)
else
    # Serial version ==> THIS VERSION WORKS FINE
    for host in ${hosts[@]};
    do
        echo "------------------ $host ------------------"

        ssh $host "$@" 2> >(sed -e "$filter1" -e "$filter2" >&2)

        echo "--------------------------------------$(echo $host | sed 's/./-/g')"
    done
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than jump through hoops trying to remove the symptom of error messages, it would be better to remove the cause.

This will assign a tty to the `ssh` session so that a terminal ioctl can be applied:

```
ssh -t $host "$@"
```

You might need to double up the `-t` flag as `-tt`, depending on how you're actually calling this line.

However, the underlying issue seems to be that you need an interactive shell to set up the conda environment. The reason for this almost certainly is that it's being set up in `~/.bashrc`. You can either `.` that explicitly or extract the relevant commands and use them in your script.

I'm not familiar with `conda` myself but the question [How do I activate a conda environment in my .bashrc?](https://askubuntu.com/q/849470/473234) on AskUbuntu seem to reference the relevant parts of your `~/.bashrc` that you would require.

Comment: The `-tt` options, coupled with `-q` to suppress `Connection to $host closed.` messages, did the trick. Thank you. I had tried to source my `.bashrc` before, but with no success. If your solution continues to work as it is now, I will stick with that.